# Using mongodb for the ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to work with the ruby on rails with the mongodb, but i can setup my application structure properly.can someone help me to start with it. any example or sample is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add `gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0.beta', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'` in your gem file.

After that add `your_app/config/mongoid.yml` file

```
development:
 clients:
   default:
     database: database_name
     hosts:
       - localhost:27017
```

Then add any `Model`, you can add number of fields

```
class Model
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :name, type: String
end
```

Then you can test using `console`.